# How to override CursorAdapter bindView

Tags: android, sqlite, overriding, android-cursor

I'm trying to display information from a `Cursor` in a `ListView`, each row contains a `ImageView` and a `TextView`. I have a `CustomCursorAdapter` extending `CursorAdapter`, in `bindView` I evaluate the data from the cursor and based on that set the views image and text.

When I run the app the `ListView` displayes the correct amount of rows, but they are empty. I know I have missed something when overriding bindView, but I'm not sure what.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
private class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

  public CustomCursorAdapter() {
    super(Lmw.this, monitorsCursor);
  }

  @Override
  public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();

    return layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
  }

  @Override
  public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    try {
      int monitorNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.MONITORS_COLUMN_MONITOR_NAME);
      int resultTotalResponseTimeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.RESULTS_COLUMN_TOTAL_RESPONSE_TIME);

      String monitorName = cursor.getString(monitorNameIndex);
      int warningThreshold = cursor.getInt(resultTotalResponseTimeIndex);

      String lbl = monitorName + "\n" + Integer.toString(warningThreshold) + " ms";

      TextView label = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);     
      label.setText(lbl);

      ImageView icon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
      if(warningThreshold < 1000) {
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);      
      } else {
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.alarm);
      }


    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      // TODO: handle exception
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try this later, but 1 comment: You should do these `cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.MONITORS_COLUMN_MONITOR_NAME);` calls in your constructor. how about you `Log.e` the exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bindView()` method seems ok.

Try replacing your *newView()* method:

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
}
```

And, for performance reasons:

- move `getLayoutInflater()` in the
  constructor
- same thing with all the `cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow()` calls,
  as **ened** already said in the
  comments
- use a StringBuilder for creating your *lbl* text
- there's no need to do *Integer.toString(warningThreshold)*...
  just use *warningThreshold*

**Later edit**:
The only difference between your `inflate()` method and the one I suggested is that this one creates layout params that match the parent.

Comment: Turns out the error was actually in my sql, the column 'RESULTS_COLUMN_TOTAL_RESPONSE_TIME' were not in the cursor. Thanks for for the feedback about the performance issues. Will mark your answer as correct.